# How do I find the current/recent photo in the WinXP "My Pictures" screensaver?

Tags: windows-xp, screensaver

My mother's laptop is using Windows XP's built-in "My Pictures Slideshow" screensaver in Display Properties. It is using the default folder `Documents and Settings\%USERNAME%\My Documents\My Pictures`

Mysteriously, sometimes pictures appear that neither she nor I can find on the computer, ones she believed were deleted. I have tried my utmost to locate them on the hard disk, but failed (the filenames would be the usual anonymous sort of thing generated by a digital camera.)

Does anyone know of a way to identify the filename and location of the photo currently being displayed, or displayed recently? The application must keep a log somewhere, as you can use the Back arrow on the keyboard to skip back to previous images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought the history might be kept somewhere in the registry, but it doesn't appear to be.  It looks like it just cycles through the pictures alphabetically or something.

However, in the screensaver settings there's an option called "Show file names".  When you turn that on, it will show the filename and path to the file on the image itself when it is displayed on the screensaver.

Comment: How did I not discover that before? Thanks! That should do it.

Comment: Aaand the mystery is solved. The missing photos were located in a hidden folder, \My Pictures\.Picasa3Temp -- no idea how that happened. (This also prevented Picasa from seeing them.) Thanks again.